# In ASP.NET Core, Is it possible to use an enum in Authorization as a policy RequireRole?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, authorization

In ASP.NET Core Authorization I want to use this enum:

```
public enum MemberRules
{
    Admin= 0,
    User = 1
}
```

On policy but I have a problem with typecasting or something like that:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
      options.AddPolicy(MemberRules.Admin, policy => policy.RequireRole(MemberRules.Admin));
      options.AddPolicy(MemberRules.User , policy => policy.RequireRole(MemberRules.User ));
    });
```

How to cast my enum to use it as RequireRole?

Answer (score 0):

Use the enum like below:

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
 {
       options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireRole(MemberRules.Admin.ToString()));
       options.AddPolicy("User", policy => policy.RequireRole(MemberRules.User.ToString()));
 });
```

Then use `[Authorize]` on the action or controller

```
 [Authorize(Policy ="Admin")]
 public IActionResult GetData()
```